# JQuery Calender for DOB to reflect changes when month, year or date is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have to use a JQuery Calendar control for Date Of Birth field and by default change in Calendar are reflect only when user selects the date, while i have been asked to make changes to reflect when either user selects month, date or year in the calendar control

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbEePe)

```
<input name="txtdob"  id="txtDOB" class="rg-txt" hasDatepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text">

 $(document).ready(function () {
  // $(function () {
             $("#txtdob").datepicker({
                 changeMonth: true,
                 changeYear: true,
                 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                 yearRange: "-90:+0"
             });
         // });
    });
```

Is there any property which i can set so that when ever user select date, month or year then same changes should reflect in the `txtDOB` input fields
UPDATED:

I did it like this

```
$(function () {
            $("#txtDOB").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                yearRange: "-90:+0",
                onChangeMonthYear: function (y, m, i) {
                    var d = i.selectedDay;
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, d));
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you try explain again, I can't understand what you mean - in date picker you select a date by choosing date, month, year but what do you expect to happen? Also, what are `txtDOB` input fields? None of your fields are named or have ID `txtDOB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

**Here's an updated codepen:** http://codepen.io/HenryGranados/pen/ObWaXX

```js
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var currentDay = date.getDate();
  $("#txtdob").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-90:+0",
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
        $(this).val(currentDay + "/"+month + "/" + year);
    }
  });
 });
```

```css
.rg-txt{
  width:200px;
  margin:50px 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input name="txtdob"  id="txtdob" class="rg-txt" hasDatepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text">
</body>

</html>
```